# How to get two text fields in interactive PDF to show same entered text - Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, interactive

I am creating an Interactive PDF from InDesign and I need to link the contents of two text fields: I need one interactive text field to be able to accept a typed value, then a second field that is in a different place to automatically fill with that same text.

I.E., In the first box the user should be able to type "$14" and $14 will show in the second box.

Can I do this with basic InDesign interactivity fields, and if so, how do I go about doing this so that the data is shown correctly in both fields in the final output interactive PDF?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have InDesign, but I know this can be accomplished in Acrobat by giving the two text boxes the same name.

Here I have two text boxes, each called `Text1`.  In the actual PDF the object IDs will have to be unique, so Acrobat managed that for me and keeps track of these by `Text1#0` and `Text#1`, which you can see in the object tree in the right-hand sidebar:

[image: PDF form with two text fields named the same]

When I edit a one text field and click away (or <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of the field), the other field is updated as well:

[image: Switching between text field in the PDF form]

I also confirmed that macOS Preview and Google Chrome exhibit the same behavior: updating one field to match the other's value.

So, if InDesign allows you to label the fields the same, that should do it.

Do you have Acrobat as well? Can you confirm that it works in Acrobat, or even save the text-field naming till last and do that in Acrobat?